# Python as a CMD data logger for time (run continously)

Tags: python

I'd like to write a python program that allows the user to key an it will write the time of the keystroke to a CSV file. E.g., a "data logger" program. The context is that we need to know the precise time that a whale dives below, so I'd like a function that when the User hits "D" it logs writes the time.

I was considering writing a function such as:

```
   from from datetime import datetime
   def D(): print datetime.now
```

... and then have the User hit "D()". But my problems are that such a program closes immediately upon running the script, rather than staying open to log further "D()" instructions from the User. Plus, the User has to hit D() instead of a more ergonomic "D"

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `time` and `csv` modules.

```
import time
import csv

with open('your_file.csv', 'w') as f:
  csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
  s = ''
  while True:
    s = raw_input("Enter 'D' to write a log event ('q' to quit): ")
    if s == 'D':
      t = time.ctime()
      csv_writer.writerow(['D press event', t])
      print 'logged a D press event at {}'.format(t)
    elif s == 'q':
      break
    elif s:
      print "You entered {}, that wasn't a D.. ;)".format(s)
```